# Python using OrderedDict for sized based caching with LRU

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary, lru

I am wondering how I can implement a size based LRU using OrderedDict. The part I am struggling with is to move the head of the linked list when I am calling `__contains__`. The following implementation is working except the `__contains__` method. It leads to infinite recursion. Any ideas how I can do that?

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class Cache(OrderedDict):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    self.size_limit = kwds.pop("size_limit", None)
    OrderedDict.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
    self.val_sum = 0
    self.hit = 0
    self.num_evicted = 0
    self.total_req = 0
    self._check_size_limit()

  def __contains__(self, key):
    self.total_req += 1
    if OrderedDict.__contains__(self, key):
       self.hit += 1
       value = OrderedDict.__getitem__ (self,key)
       self.move_item_to_the_top(key, value)
       return True
    else:
       return False

  def move_item_to_the_top(self, key, value):
    OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
    self.val_sum += value
    self._check_size_limit()

  def _check_size_limit(self):
    if self.size_limit is not None:
      while self.val_sum > self.size_limit:
        key, value = self.popitem(last=False)
        self.val_sum -= value 
        self.num_evicted += 1

  def get_cache_size(self):
    return self.val_sum

  def get_number_evicted(self):
    return self.num_evicted

  def get_hit_ratio(self):
    return 1.00 * self.hit / self.total_req

  def get_total_req(self):
    return self.total_req

  def get_hits(self):
    return self.hit
```

This is how I am using this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":


  cache_size_B = 10
  cache = Cache(size_limit=cache_size_B)

  items = [(1,3), (2,3), (1,3), (3,4), (1,3), (5,5)]


  for item in items:

    cache_key = str(item[0])
    obj_size = item[1]
    print item

    if cache_key not in cache:
        cache[cache_key] = int(obj_size)

    print cache
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way, but couldn't you pop the key and then set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your code I get the following error:

```
python cache.py
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
(1, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cache.py", line 68, in <module>
    if cache_key not in cache:
  File "cache.py", line 20, in __contains__
    self.move_item_to_the_top(key, value)
  File "cache.py", line 26, in move_item_to_the_top
    OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 75, in __setitem__
    if key not in self:
  File "cache.py", line 20, in __contains__
    self.move_item_to_the_top(key, value)
  File "cache.py", line 26, in move_item_to_the_top
    OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 75, in __setitem__
    if key not in self:

[...]

  File "cache.py", line 26, in move_item_to_the_top
    OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 75, in __setitem__
    if key not in self:
  File "cache.py", line 20, in __contains__
    self.move_item_to_the_top(key, value)
  File "cache.py", line 26, in move_item_to_the_top
    OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__
```

Looking at line 75 of `collections.py` it reveals that your calling back `Cache.__contains__` which leads to the infinite loop.

You could rewrite the `Cache` class without overiding `__contains__` and instead use `Cache.__getitem__` to track access to the cache:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


class Cache(OrderedDict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.size_limit = kwds.pop("size_limit", None)
        OrderedDict.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.val_sum = 0
        self.hit = 0
        self.num_evicted = 0
        self.total_req = 0
        self._check_size_limit()

    def move_item_to_the_top(self, key, value):
        del self[key]
        OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self.total_req += 1
        try:
            value = OrderedDict.__getitem__(self, key)
        except KeyError:
            raise
        else:
            self.hit += 1
            self.move_item_to_the_top(key, value)
            return value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        self.val_sum += value
        self._check_size_limit()

    def _check_size_limit(self):
        if self.size_limit is not None:
            while self.val_sum > self.size_limit:
                key, value = self.popitem(last=False)
                self.val_sum -= value 
                self.num_evicted += 1

    def get_cache_size(self):
        return self.val_sum

    def get_number_evicted(self):
        return self.num_evicted

    def get_hit_ratio(self):
        return 1.00 * self.hit / self.total_req

    def get_total_req(self):
        return self.total_req

    def get_hits(self):
        return self.hit


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cache_size_B = 10
    cache = Cache(size_limit=cache_size_B)

    items = [(1,3), (2,3), (1,3), (3,4), (1,3), (5,5)]

    for item in items:

        cache_key = str(item[0])
        obj_size = item[1]
        print item

        try:
            cache[cache_key]
        except KeyError:
            cache[cache_key] = int(obj_size)

    print cache
```

You can still use `foo not in cache` but this will not count as a miss or hit. If you want to count *any* access use the prefered syntax `try/except` [1]  , e.g.:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cache_size_B = 10
    cache = Cache(size_limit=cache_size_B)

    items = [(1,3), (2,3), (1,3), (3,4), (1,3), (5,5)]

    for item in items:

        cache_key = str(item[0])
        obj_size = item[1]
        print item

        try:
            cache[cache_key]
        except KeyError:
            cache[cache_key] = int(obj_size)

    print cache
```

[1] This is the prefered syntax to conditionaly do something based on the existance or not of an item in a list or dict because it requires only a single access to the container.

Comment: In `move_to_the_top` method, you need to remove the item (by calling `__delitem__`), otherwise it won't move it to the top. However, I am still wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The docs have a recipe for this, you could see it here : https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

```
class LRU(OrderedDict):
    'Limit size, evicting the least recently looked-up key when full'

    def __init__(self, maxsize=128, *args, **kwds):
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        super().__init__(*args, **kwds)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = super().__getitem__(key)
        self.move_to_end(key)
        return value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        if len(self) > self.maxsize:
            oldest = next(iter(self))
            del self[oldest]
```